# How to check keys and values of Hashmap using function and then return output?

Tags: javascript

I created Hashmap array with keys and values:

```
 var rule = 
 {
  "c": "d",
  "a": "o",
  "t": "g",
  "h": "a",
  "e": "n",
  "n": "t",
 }
```

Now I want to create function that check above arrays which returns values respective to keys given input.
i.e Suppose if I give input "cat" then it must give output "dog" according to hashmap value.

Note: This can be easily done by using switch case where value of the expression is compared with the values of each case and we return output if there is a match.

But I am looking for more reliable method where we can create function that check above arrays which returns values respective to keys given input. i.e Input = cat then Output = dog

Comment: How about if the input value is `cen`, output value is `dnt`?

Comment: @TânNguyễn For cen,we need to define its key in hashmap as "cen" and values as "dnt".

Comment: @SumanBasnet I see you have added another question to understand my answer. You have any query? i can help

Comment: @NitishNarang I understood it finally.Thank you for your effort

Comment: @SumanBasnet That's great!! In future as well if you need any clarity for any answer you can directly ask user :) All the best

Comment: Also @SumanBasnet you can mark helper answer as accepted solution so that fellow users get to know your issue is resolved.

Comment: @NitishNarang I didn't know about accepting solution.Thank for letting me know,I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using `Array.map`

```js
var rule = 
 {
  "c": "d",
  "a": "o",
  "t": "g",
  "h": "a",
  "e": "n",
  "n": "t",
 }
 
 function output(str) {
  return [...str].map(d => rule[d]).join('')
 }
 
 console.log(output('cat'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code returns `dog`.  The assumption is that order of input string does not matter.  e.g. `tac` will return `god`

```
var rule = 
 {
  "c": "d",
  "a": "o",
  "t": "g",
  "h": "a",
  "e": "n",
  "n": "t",
 };

 const input = "cat";
 let output = "";

 for (let value of input) {
    console.log(rule[value]);
    output += rule[value];
}

console.log(output);
```

You will have to handle the edge cases like those keys not present in the hash.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following function :

```
function returnValue(){ 
  var result = "";
    for(var i=0;i<arguments.length;i++){
    result+=rule[arguments[i]];
}
return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that accepts an obj and iterate through it, using given keys:

```js
 var rule = 
 {
  "c": "d",
  "a": "o",
  "t": "g",
  "h": "a",
  "e": "n",
  "n": "t",
 }
    
    function keys(obj)
    {
        var values = [];
    
        for(var key in obj)
        {
           values.push(obj[key]);
        }
    
        return values;
    }

    console.log(keys(rule));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use inline code, you can use `Objec.keys`

```js
var rule = 
{
  "c": "d",
  "a": "o",
  "t": "g",
  "h": "a",
  "e": "n",
  "n": "t"
};
 
var input = 'cat';

var output = Object.keys(rule).filter(x => input.indexOf(x) !== -1)
                   .map(x => rule[x]).join('');

console.log(output);
```

If the input value is `cen`, the output value should be `dnt`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var rule = 
{
  "c": "d",
  "a": "o",
  "t": "g",
  "h": "a",
  "e": "n",
  "n": "t"
};

let input = 'cat';

let output = input.split('').map(key =>rule[key]).join("");

console.log(`Result: ${output}`);
```